# Leaving Thailand after months-long overstay (can't pay fine)

Tags: us-citizens, thailand, overstaying

I missed my plane after staying just a couple weeks in Thailand and stayed with my girlfriend. I ended up out of money and no ticket home. I keep hearing about staying a day over here, but nothing about a few months over. I have stayed here for 6 months, so overstayed by about 5 months now.

I never had a visa, because I was only going to stay for a couple of weeks. Now I finally was able to get a ticket home and I'm not sure how to go about it.

I barely got enough money for a ticket and can't pay the fine, which I am sure is 20,000 baht by now.

What is there for me to do?

Comment: How long will your overstay period be (the amount of time you stayed after you were supposed to leave)?

Comment: Since 20k is the maximum amount you can be fined, I think it's sufficient to know it's more than 40 days

Comment: Let us know when you got out of Thailand. Else we can place a banner around your user profile [DETAINED]. Good luck.

Comment: Although it's a minor issue, I'm struggling to understand how a missed plane turned into multi-month over stay.  You might reconsider using that as your excuse.

Comment: @NotMe It may have started with a non-refundable non-changeable ticket and insufficient funds to buy a replacement. At that point belak should have immediately contacted their country's consulate or embassy to ask for help and advice.

Comment: Said labor is unlikely to be particularly honest while on a tourist visa unless perhaps you are in a position to find and do a job remotely online. And 20k Baht is [a considerable amount of money](http://www.livingthai.org/how-much-is-the-average-thai-salary-per-month.html) given the typical wages in Thailand.

Comment: I've been here 6 months so it's a bit over 5 months over stay... I was just curious if there was a way to pay the fine and catch my plane... I just didn't look into much of the laws or really much of anything before I came... can't find work here... I stayed multiple months due to lack of funds and didn't want to leave my girlfriend as well... I'm poor in America as well,  so getting this ticket now was kind of a lucky thing... thanks for trying...  I'm just trying to get home...  thanks again

Comment: @belak You're going to need to be your own best advocate now, as not doing anything will probably just make the problem worse. Contact the consulate and seek as much help from them as they can provide. Get in touch with family and friends. Try contacting the charitable organizations in [this article](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/why-are-so-many-westerners-homeless-in-thailand-8830302.html) and any others that could help. Good luck to you.

Comment: Also note that you are not allowed to work in Thailand, like most countries, on a tourist visa. You would need some sort of Thai work permit for that. Working illegally could greatly compound your problems, plus you'd be working for the kind of people who hire illegal workers, which could leave you with little recourse if things go south.

Comment: I am looking into the ACS in the embassy for a loan or charitable places... thank you very much for that link.. I have been looking for a while now how to get home and just being able to get a ticket is great and having you guys help is great too..  I was just dumb about it... going to marry this girl.., talked to her for years before I could finally meet her... it was hard to leave... I have always ran in half cocked but I see there are some times to plan hahahaha.... I know I messed up but thank you all for trying to help....

Comment: My family could only scrape up this much for a ticket.... I swear if I ever got kidnapped for ransom because I am American I would be screwed.... my family has no money... but again seriously thank you all for trying to help... means a lot

Comment: Can't your girlfriend help you?

Comment: What's your native country?

Comment: @Christian "...I am American" (two comments above yours). It's a safe bet "American" means US here.

Comment: @CompuChip: couldn't you sell some of your stuff back home? 20,000 bht is $600, and this is an emergency (that is, it's worth doing whatever to get the money).

Comment: @QuoraFeans I like my stuff and the place where I am, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: @CompuChip: you also like not being in prison, probably.

Comment: @QuoraFeans I guess not, but I have no intention of going there in _any_ country. I think you have me confused for OP (though he probably won't like it either).

Comment: @CompuChip: oh, yes. I confused you with belak. Don't sell your stuff then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41204/discussion-between-compuchip-and-quora-feans).

Comment: As you'll probably be temporarily banned from entering Thailand, prepare yourself for not seeing her for a while (as she apparently can't help you I assume she won't be able to gather money to travel to the US to see you) - And please do not use that as an excuse to make matters worse for yourself by staying.

Comment: Whatever happens, please come back and report how it went. This could be a life-saver for future travelers!

Comment: @JonathanReez Yes, OP. Please don't abandon this post. Give updates!

Comment: So I got to the airport and paid the fine and signed some papers and that was it... booted for a year, but that was it... last minute I got a loan for the fine... I'm sure it would've been different had I not had the fine money... thanks for all the info people

Comment: @belak maybe you could add that as an update to your question so it's not lost in the comments. Thanks for coming back and updating!

Comment: Actually, this is so useful that belak could consider posting it as an actual answer. @Henders

Answer (score 132):

This question has been asked many times, so I guess you've already found some nice resources ([one](http://www.thaivisa.com/visa-overstay-thailand.html), [two](http://www.thaiembassy.com/thailand/overstay-visa-thailand.php)) on this topic.

1. You **will** pay the 20,000 THB fine. Possibly, more. Possibly, after imprisonment.
2. You **will** receive the "overstay" stamp in your passport.
3. Possibly, you'll get banned from entering the Kingdom, temporarily or permanently; The biggest issue is that you may not be informed about this right in place and get an unpleasant surprise on your *next* visit.
4. **Your goal is to try to avoid imprisonment.**

If failed to pay the overstay fine, you'll most certainly get detained and imprisoned.

So, your actions are:

1. Call your Embassy and ask for instructions as they know the thing better than strangers at StackExchange;
2. Ask for a money transfer from your family or friends;
3. Avoid exposing yourself to random police checks, even on your way to the airport. Don't drive the car/bike, don't visit places where random checks can occur (beer bars, disco, etc);
4. Get safely to the airport; **you will need several hours to get through all the process, so come early**;
5. Walk up to the Immigration counter, hand your return ticket, pay the fine.
6. Expect for a shame of being handcuffs-escorted to the plane.
7. **Never ever overstay anymore.**

P.S. Jail in Thailand usually means a small crowded room with no furniture or even fan, lots of mosquitoes, sleeping on a concrete floor, and foreigners even need to pay for their meals.
Don't expose yourself for that.

Comment: Indeed, the old 'pay the fine or do the time' applies here as in so many situations.

Comment: "strangers at StackExchange" man, the combined first hand experiences here are much better than some embassy employees.

Comment: "Ask for a money transfer from your family or friends" you'll need to find a way to make that request sound real because on first glance it will sound like a scam.

Comment: @Brad Google Hangouts (or the like), if you can.

Comment: 20.000 baht is about €500 / $570. You could consider a social funding site to raise the money, if your family and friends are not able/willing to help you.

Comment: @KlaymenDK I doubt total strangers on the internet will be running to provide funds for this situation.

Comment: @gerrit [you](http://www.rantgizmo.com/2015/10/14/15-dumbest-gofundme-campaigns-of-all-time/) [might be](http://bossip.com/1113775/get-a-job-funniest-craziest-shadiest-gofundme-campaigns/2/) [surprised](http://www.ranker.com/list/dumb-gofundme-campaigns/ashley-reign)

Comment: @Mitch Most of those have raised next-to-nothing.

Comment: @gerrit Most screenshots at least 1 person donated some amount. With the right sob story you can attract anyone ;)

Comment: Max fine is 20k and you will never get permanently banned.

Comment: The ban is max 10 years. If OP leaves this year it will be 1 year ban.

Answer (score 83):

If you voluntarily exit, you will be fined 500 baht per day of overstay (maximum amount of 20,000 baht), you will not go to jail.

If you are caught by police overstaying, you will face criminal charges and higher fines.  Jail time tends to alloted primarily for really long overstays (as in years), not for minor overstays.

If your overstay is less than 90 days, your passport will be marked as an overstay and any future visits will be subjected to proving your tourist  intentions (departing tickets, funding, hotel bookings).

If your overstay is more than 90 days you will be banned from the country for 1 year in situation one (voluntary) or 5 years in situation two (arrested).  Overstaying by one year would be 3 and 10 year bans respectively.

http://overstay.immigration.go.th/advice.html

If you can't pay the fine, you will be at the mercy of the immigration officer handling your case. He could simply clean out your wallet and send you packing home, he could press legal charges against you, he could choose to deport you which could have ramifications on future visas or visits anywhere, etc. You really need to secure funds before going to the airport, contact friends family back home, ask your buddies in Thailand, contact your embassy about loans, etc.

Comment: Yeah and most importantly, the immigration officer can detain you. Indefinitely if you cannot pay your ticket back.

Comment: @dan-klasson OP has commented on the question that they do have a ticket home now.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Yes, but maybe he loses this ticket, if arrested, and have to buy a new one.

Comment: @QuoraFeans - one could argue a million whatifs, but that doesn't address the OP's specific questions.

Comment: @Tom: getting delayed by immigration and missing a flight at an airline company that does not allow re-schedule implies losing a ticket. I don't mean just a casual possibility, but something pretty probable.

Answer (score 47):

Here's what actually happened to the OP (as indicated in [a comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71284/leaving-thailand-after-months-long-overstay-cant-pay-fine/71310#comment165962_71284)):

> So I got to the airport and paid the fine and signed some papers and
>   that was it... booted for a year, but that was it... last minute I got
>   a loan for the fine... I'm sure it would've been different had I not
>   had the fine money... thanks for all the info people.

Someone suggested to the OP that this information is so valuable that it shouldn't be a mere comment, but edited into OP itself. I think OP should actually make this an answer himself, but until he does, I'm putting it here as a Community Wiki answer.

Comment: I never saw the update, so thanks for highlighting it here. Glad the OP got out.

Comment: OP, if you see this answer, please consider making your own answer where you provide even more details. You can then comment on this answer and I will delete it.

Answer (score 10):

Let the US consulate know, when you plan to fly back.

Also ask them for advice. I am pretty sure this happens to other people.

This is the official Thai gov advice: http://overstay.immigration.go.th/advice.html

Do everything possible to gather the money. 20,000 bht is $600. Whatever you can sell to get these $600 will be worthwhile.

Report the situation to the nearest immigration office by yourself and come clean. If they catch you, things will be different. Do this with enough time before the flight, not just 2-3 hours before the flight. Otherwise, you could miss your flight.

This is the official Thai gov advice: http://overstay.immigration.go.th/advice.html They draw a line between surrendering and being caught.

Do not approach immigration before you gathered the money.

Comment: Why the US consulate?  Will they help the OP if he is not American?

Comment: @AndyBrown:  the OP is American.

Comment: $600 is not much. Get it. Even dirt poor and broke as hell in the USA $600 is much better then jail time in a foreign prison. Borrow it, use a credit card or three, sell everything you own. Sell your car, your cloths, your house, your dog, everything if that's what it takes. If you end up in prison, it's just gonna make it so much worse.

Comment: @coteyr: yes, and he will still need to pay to get out of prison. So, to pay or not to pay is not an option.

Comment: @coteyr There is not so bad in prisons in Thailand. My friend has 1 month Thai jail, and now he has some experience in Thaiboxing.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: was he the punching bag?