# Overstayed in the Philippines for years: How to go back to the US without paying a big fine?

Tags: us-citizens, overstaying, philippines

I'm a U.S. Citizen and I have been overstaying in the Philippines for 5 years. I want to go back to U.S what's the penalty?

I don't have enough money to pay a big fine, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: You're question didn't really make sense (to me at least), you already seemed to know what the (maximum?) penalty is… I have tried to reformulate it, hope that's OK.

Comment: Approximates for the penalty see [here](http://www.in-philippines.com/how-much-are-the-penalties-for-overstaying-as-a-tourist-in-the-philippines/). [This site](http://liveinthephilippines.com/content/what-happens-if-you-overstay-your-visa/) says if you can't pay your fees you go to jail until you can pay. No need to say your smartest move would be to contact [your embassy](https://ph.usembassy.gov/).

Comment: Also, if you ask around, there will be people offering to "fix" your situation for a fee. The vast majority, if not all of them, will simply rip you off.

Comment: Wasn't there a question like this not too long ago with the same problem risking a fine of 20,000 in local currency?

Comment: @Mast You're probably thinking of [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71284/leaving-thailand-after-months-long-overstay-cant-pay-fine/) about Thailand. Apparently, the user was able to find someone to loan them the cost of the fine. The fine here looks like it will be several times that though.

Comment: $6,000 USD fine, eh?  Sounds like it would be cheaper to buy yourself an immigration official or two.

Comment: @ZachLipton Yes, that one. Thanks for the link. It's not a duplicate, but related enough to deserve mentioning.

Comment: You made your bed. Lie in it. Pay your fine or go to jail.

Comment: Wondering why this has only occurred you now that you want to go back, when you know you've been an illegal for five _years_?

Comment: "go to jail until you can pay"
How does that work? Can one earn money in jail?

Comment: you could avoid it by getting a boat and heading to another country and then flying home from there..... though the cost of this will match the cost of the fines, and it'll be a lot more inconvenient

Comment: @AnsisMāliņš the idea is that debtor must contact friends, relatives, embassy, etc while in jail. Until someone else pays the debts, the debtor remains in jail. This used to be a very common punishment in the past, in many parts of the world.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debtors%27_prison

Answer (score 33):

[As noted in one of the comments](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79004/overstayed-in-the-philippines-for-years-how-to-go-back-to-the-us-without-paying#comment177474_79004), your fine [could be as much as 300,000 Philippine pesos](http://www.in-philippines.com/how-much-are-the-penalties-for-overstaying-as-a-tourist-in-the-philippines/), which is about $6300 at the moment.  Being unable to pay, particularly given your very lengthy overstay, will probably result in a significant prison term, and/or stay in an immigration detention center, neither of which are a place you want to be.

Bottom line, you need to get together enough money to pay the fine, or you'll  you'll get a taste of hell on earth.  If you don't have people you can beg or borrow enough from, you should consult with the US embassy about the [repatriation loan program](https://web.archive.org/web/20161215025428/https://tirana.usembassy.gov/repat-loan.html)* and other assistance they can offer, which can include a waiver or reduction in immigration overstay fees.

<sup>*The link is to a different embassy's site, but it's a [State Department program](https://web.archive.org/web/20170413170459/http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/123611.pdf), not an embassy specific thing.</sup>

> As authorized by section 4 of the State Department Basic Authorities Act, the Department of
> State‘s Repatriation Loans program provides emergency loans to assist destitute Americans
> abroad who have no other source of funds to return to the United States. They include Americans
> temporarily abroad who are without funds because of unforeseen events such as theft, illness, or
> accident; individuals suffering from serious physical or mental illness who need to return to the
> United States for medical care; Americans residing abroad with an alien spouse needing
> assistance to escape an abusive situation; and individuals caught in a disaster or emergency
> abroad who need to be removed from harm‘s way. Approval of a repatriation loan is not based on
> an applicant‘s credit worthiness but rather destitution. State repatriation loans are provided for
> temporary subsistence and transportation to a U.S. port of entry.

Comment: though whether the loan would ever be repaid by someone who knowingly breaks the law for years and then wants to break the law again by wanting to leave a country illegally in order to not have to face the consequences of the first crime...

Comment: @jwenting: then it's a stroke of luck for the questioner that approval is not based on creditworthiness.

Comment: @jwenting The state (especially your home country) has more extensive means to contrain payment than private and/or foreign creditors so the program makes sense. But the fact is that there is also such a thing as a bail bondsman, which is a fascinating thing in itself.

Comment: @Relaxed of course it makes sense that a country would have such a system in place. Just wondering what the chances are for the government to ever get their money back from OP. I'm well aware of the powers of governments to collect payment from citizens, I work for a government collections agency :)

Comment: In particular, the US government can limit a US passport to a single trip to the US, and then refuse to issue a replacement until the loan is repaid.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan And that is one of the warnings about the program - your passport will be "restricted"  and will be unable to get a renewal or new one until you've paid the loan off.

Comment: As written, that says its purpose is for the cost of returning.  Arguable whether that includes fines for overstay.  Either way, best thing to do is go to the Embassy and ask for help.

Comment: @WGroleau [Some of the Department of State's internal documentation on the program](https://fam.state.gov/fam/07fam/07fam0370.html) does include examples where a repatriation loan is used to pay for immigration fines - section 7 FAM 376.2 in the linked doc.

Answer (score 28):

There's an online site [liveinthephilippines](http://liveinthephilippines.com/content/what-happens-if-you-overstay-your-visa/) that covers this:

> If you have overstayed, and go to the airport to leave, they will
>   catch you, there is no way around it.  What happens if you don’t have
>   the money to pay the fines that are due?  Well, if you can’t pay they
>   still won’t let you leave, but they also will not release you.  No,
>   they have a place for you to stay!  In jail. Most people who are
>   jailed for immigration matters are sent to the Bicutan Prison in
>   Taguig.  You will stay there until you pay the fines.

It does depend a lot on your type of visa, and whether you go and pay the fees / fines in advance, instead of upon being caught, from the sounds of it.  You will also likely be blacklisted if it's been longer than 12 months.

I'd have a read of that article - but the short version is - you're paying the fees, or potentially serving some jail time until you do.  Maybe consult a lawyer for more advice too, and the US Embassy.  Good luck!

Comment: Holy expletive you do not want to end up there. It is essential to pay that fine and quickly

Comment: So when a person has no funds available from outside the prison to pay the fine they will essentially be sentenced to life? There is hardly a way to make money while in prison.

Comment: @Phillipp

I think that website is probably wrong; I'm guessing if you don't pay the fine you'll be jailed for a particular duration.

Comment: @RamchandraApte You say that, but it looks like a pretty bad place to end up to me http://www.scmp.com/magazines/post-magazine/article/1846705/forgotten-foreigners-notorious-philippine-detention-centre Also you can't really make money, but you can be held until some friends or family or whatever get some money to you. I think it's supposed to be a kind of pretty brutal deterrent. That and you're basically held hostage if the scmp link is to be taken at face value, they'll hang on to you until someone pays to get you out. opportunity for bribes, too, of course. i'd get that fine paid. now

Comment: This was popular a long time ago in europe, it was called "debter's prison" were you stayed forever until your debt was paid by you or someone else.

Comment: If it really is until paid, this makes going to the US embassy a good idea. You are a US citizen you should be able to claim a defense against an unconscionable local law.

Comment: What about leaving by ferry to a neighbouring country?

Comment: @hippietrail The OP would probably run into issues trying to leave (assuming he can get on the ferry at all), since he has a U.S. passport, no entry visa and the last entry stamp was (presumably) in the Philippines.  Perhaps he can get around it with a bribe, but at that point it's probably cheaper to just pay the fine...

Comment: @hippietrail  Out of the frying pan and into the fire.  For one thing, official, legal travel to a neighboring country will have immigration controls where they'd catch someone with such a long overstay, and if it doesn't, then you'd have the same problem of being in the neighboring country illegally, and subject to fines and criminal penalties for that.

Comment: Is this from experience with international ferries in the Philippines, or just an assumption? I've taken plenty of international ferries in other parts of the world and at least on the boarding side they're close to always slacker than airports. Things are much more official on the arrival side but still can be slacker than airports, at least at checking my status in the country in which I boarded. The neighbouring country might not throw people into debtors prison either. By the way, the ferry I know of is in the muslim south where it's dangerous for foreigners, but there may be others.

Answer (score 13):

Actually, you can ask the US Embassy for help. The consul will write a letter to the Commissioner of the Bureau of Immigration. They will let you out, the consequence would then be going back. Because they will put you in the Blacklist and you won't be allowed to enter the Philippines unless you pay the fine. This happened to me so I know. If there is no need for you to be back in PH then you can just directly do that. I actually went back to the Philippines a few months ago. I paid the fine of almost half a million pesos - $7,700 dollars.