# Overstaying in the Philippines. Can I pay the fine and continue my stay?

Tags: visas, legal, overstaying, philippines

I have overstayed my visit to the Philippines by two years.  After paying the fines, can I stay in the Philippines as long as I have a valid visa?

Comment: I don't know about Philippine law, but in the places I *am* familiar with your overstay will have invalidated any visa you held at the time, while at the same time ruining your chances of receiving a new visa in the future, at least in the short term, and possibly in the long term.

Comment: i am not sure how they behave but it is hard to get a valid visa because you already overstayed there with one visa. Better you consult a lawyer.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79004/overstayed-in-the-philippines-for-years-how-to-go-back-to-the-us-without-paying

Comment: You seem to be viewing the fine as a payment for a service; it's not: it's a punishment for breaking the law.

Answer (score 9):

You are mistaken. You could be in serious trouble. [See](http://www.in-philippines.com/how-much-are-the-penalties-for-overstaying-as-a-tourist-in-the-philippines/)

> **Overstaying Foreigners in the Philippines**
>
> Foreigners who have overstayed for more than twelve (12) months
>   regardless if their stay is within the maximum allowable period or
>   those found to be overstaying by virtue to a complaint or Mission
>   Order regardless of the period **shall be referred for deportation.**

You could also be blacklisted per the law. A two year overstay on a visitors visa virtually everywhere in the world will be considered harshly.That indicates a blatant disregard for the immigration rules.

Comment: But then again, in the Philippines, you can just pay the right people and all will be forgiven.