# Overstayed in the Philippines for over 2 years but I want to stay here permanently

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, overstaying, philippines

I'm a US citizen who moved here 2 years ago when I was 18 to be with my girlfriend. My visa has long expired because I never had the funds to pay for the extension fees when I needed to. Now, I have a job online but it's still not enough to pay for the big amount for overstaying for over 2 years here, but I can save up for it in just a few months, but my longterm plan is to marry my Filipina girlfriend I came here for and live here permanently, but also be able to travel within the country and maybe in the future, outside as well (so I can take her to meet my family in the US). Is there a way to fix my visa issues but still be able to live here in the Philippines at this point?

Comment: You probably wrecked it...

Comment: Plain objectively speaking, you're an illegal immigrant, and to my knowledge the Philippines don't take very kindly to those. You're certainly not getting permanent residency based on marriage as an illegal immigrant, and in fact your marriage may well not be recognised in the first place

Comment: If I were you, I'd make an anonymous call to the Immigration Bureau, or, better yet, see a skilled Immigration lawyer

Comment: @Coke do you by chance know of a very skilled Immigration lawyer?

Comment: @Needhelp Sadly not (I'm not too specialised on that country I'm afraid) but this seems to be one place for searching https://www.hg.org/law-firms/immigration/philippines.html

Comment: @Needhelp Better yet, fill out this form, and explain your Situation in Detail https://www.hg.org/contactus.asp

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89600/overstaying-in-the-philippines-can-i-pay-the-fine-and-continue-my-stay