# Question about my mom (US citizen) returning to USA after overstaying abroad

Tags: us-citizens, overstaying, philippines, fines

My mother is a US citizen but overstayed in the philippines for 3 yrs now due to 2 of my brothers had a stroke and 1 passed away,and now she is looking after my other brother.Iwant to her to return to the US anytime soon.What is your advice?She will be 90 yrs old in a couple of months.

Comment: What is the question you need help with? As it stands it's not clear what you're confused about.

Comment: If your mother is an American (US) citizen, then once her identity/citizenship is proven (generally by a passport), she cannot be refused entry into the United States of America. She  may have problems entering other countries, however

Comment: She may or will have problems entering the Philippines. No problems with the US whatsoever as long as she can prove she's American, i.e. a US passport.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overstayed in the Philippines for years: How to go back to the US without paying a big fine?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79004/overstayed-in-the-philippines-for-years-how-to-go-back-to-the-us-without-paying)

Comment: It's worth noting, however, that if she has an _expired_ US passport, the airline may refuse to board her for a US-bound flight.

Comment: If the question, mentioned as duplicate, does not answer your question, please edit this question with what you exactly need to know.