# Overstaying In Philippines

Tags: us-citizens, overstaying, philippines

Overstayed in Philippines for 18 years. I wanna go back in Hawaii. But i have no money. Also my passport lost 3 years ago. I don't know what to do. Not enough money to go home.

Answer (score 2):

You have to approach US embassy in Philipines and explain the situation. US embassy can help you getting a new passport and emergency loan to repatriate you back to USA.

But rest assured that you have to pay the amount back and US might restrict you from leaving USA until you paid back the amount.

Comment: but what about the money..? not enough money to get a new passport and for a flights

Comment: @AliaMoral Anish Sheela's answer covers this issue in its second sentence. The US Embassy in the Philipines can make or arrange funding to pay for your return.

Comment: and the cost of overstaying..?

Comment: @AliaMoral US government will loan you money for that. Contact your embassy. Never contact Philippines authority now.

Comment: See - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79004/overstayed-in-the-philippines-for-years-how-to-go-back-to-the-us-without-paying?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://fam.state.gov/fam/07fam/07fam0370.html

Answer (score 2):

You have a big problem.

You'll be referred for deportation ([Source](http://immigration.gov.ph/2-uncategorised/234-honorable-secretary)), but that is the least of your worries.

The fine for overstaying is PHP500 per month. If you have overstayed 18 years the fine will be over PHP100,000 (one hundred thousand); about US$2000. There will also be some administrative charges but they're small by comparison.

If you can't pay the fine you'll be detained until you can.

Contact the US embassy and ask for advice. Obviously you'll need to renew your passport. They might be able to help with the money, but dont count on it.

I suggest you don't contact the Philippines authorities until you have money to pay the fine. Things will be much more difficult to resolve from prison.

Comment: but not enough money to renew my passport and the flights..

Comment: @AliaMoral US government will loan you money for passport, flight and possibly to pay fine also. Contact embassy and embassy only.