# Overstayed by 11 years in the Philippines

Tags: usa, overstaying, philippines, citizen

My son has overstayed his visa and has been living in the Philippines for 11 years. I would like to bring him back to the United States. I am unsure of the amount of fines he would have to pay. I would like to avoid going to the Bureau of Immigration if I do not have enough money to cover the fines. Does anyone know how much the fines cost?

Also, is it safe to travel to the Philippines now? What documents would I need to travel?

Comment: Is he a Philippine citizen?

Comment: Please check https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79004/overstayed-in-the-philippines-for-years-how-to-go-back-to-the-us-without-paying - especially the bottom answer.

Comment: How old is your son?

Comment: Regarding the travel, you might be subjected to a mandatory quarantine. You can check the details here: https://covid19travel.com/#Philippines